# How to make index list table view with Core Data, iOS Dev

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have an Entity in core data called "Expense" with attributes "Date, Category, Amount..........". How can I list all the expenses with index list, based on "Year-Month" from Date attribute?

From apple's document and tutorials, I know how to make index list table view. But it requires to provide "Array of arrays". That's one array for all sections, and one sub-array for objects in one specific section. Now my data structure is not like this.

From my thinking, what I can do is:

1. fetch all the expenses first, then extract all cases of "Year-Month" with no duplication, put them into an array, which is for all the sections
2. then I fetch all the expenses based on every section

But I think it's kind of heavy work, can I achieve this more conveniently? Or should I change my data structure ?
Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a request to return only the expenses in the given range:

```
//Not tested
NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger year,month;//set these as you like
[comps setYear:year];
[comps setMonth:month];
NSDate* start = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
month += 1;
month = (month <= 12 ? : 1);
[comps setMonth:month];
NSDate* end = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date > %@ AND date < %@",start,end];
NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Expense"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Then use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate your table view

Comment: thanks for your answer, but from your solution, you know the year and month before you fetch the data. But the year and month should be read from data at first. isn't it?  :) anyway, I think I can do it, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, but the basic idea is to use an NSFetchedResultsController to display the data and an NSPredicate to do the filtering.

I'd also strongly recommend you have a look at frameworks such as Sensible TableView as it will be able to help you automatically display and filter out of the box.